# Add custom message (not error) under under combobox/text field

Tags: extjs

I'm new to extjs and I'm looking for a way to add some custom message under my combobox field.

Depending on some conditions (eg. value selected) the message needs to have different text and/or style.

I could play with errorEl associated with my combobox and change it's message/style depending on the state, but this doesnt look like a good approach.

Are you aware of any plugin allowing to add such a message, or is there a shorter way to do this?

---

Thank you for your suggestions. I ended up writing my own plugin, which then I attached to combobox.

I added new element after error element and I changed messages based on proper combobox events.

```
afterCmpRender : function() {
    var me = this, cmp = me.getCmp();

    var messageWrapper = {
        tag : 'div'
    };
    var messageEl = cmp.errorEl.insertSibling(messageWrapper, "after");
    cmp.messageEl = messageEl;

    Ext.Array.each(me.messages, function(message) {
        var messageConfig = {
            tag : 'div',
            style : {
                display : 'none'
            }
        };
        var newElement = messageEl.insertSibling(messageConfig, "after");
        newElement.setHTML(message.value);
        newElement.addCls(message.classes);
        me.registerMessageEvents(me, cmp, message, newElement);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I almost always use multiple elements for this, and would not make an attempt to change the field.

Depending on your context, which you didn't provide, I'd say you could have a look at:

- `Ext.form.field.Display`
- `Ext.form.Label`
- `Ext.tip.Tip`
- `Ext.tip.QuickTip`

Answer (score 1):

I'd work with the class `Ext.tip.Tip`.

You can create

```
Ext.create('Ext.tip.Tip', {
    id: 'myTip',
    header: false
});
```

and then

```
var tip = Ext.getCmp('myTip');
tip.update('your custom tip message');
tip.showBy(comboboxComponent);
```

You could also use `showAt(..)` instead of `showBy`.
For more information look into the [Docu](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tip.Tip-method-showAt)

Here is a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/9uc) link to an example.